# Are NewGlobalRef / DeleteGlobalRef calls "recursive"?

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface

A very basic question, but I don't see it explained anywhere in the docs. Say I have a `jobject` (or `jclass`). I create a global ref (`NewGlobalRef`) and store it for later use. Then I create another one and store it again. Then I delete the second ref, then I delete the first one. Will it work as I expected - ensuring the object is kept alive and all non-deleted references valid as long as the number of `NewGlobalRef` calls is greater than the number of `DeleteGlobalRef` calls for this object?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Each JNI global and local reference is an individual garbage collection root. Roots refer to the first objects considered alive during a mark and sweep. An single object could have any number JNI references to it.

Of course, objects can reference other objects, so just because you delete all JNI references to an object doesn't mean it's no longer alive.

As for "recursive", I thought you meant something else. JNI references just reference heap objects and are not heap objects themselves. So, there is no recursion involved.

Some further reading at IBM's [Overview of JNI object references](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.lnx.80.doc/diag/understanding/jni_refs.html).

Comment: Thank you. I called it recursion as an analogy to a recursive mutex, for the lack of better word. I realize `DeleteGlobalRef` may not cause the object to be deleted immediately, which is perfectly fine. My problem is that global references become invalid for an unknown reason, so I decided to find out if they're even supposed to work the way I expected.

Comment: IBM's knowledge center has lots of useful articles. Let me fix the link to the right one - [Overview of JNI object references](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.lnx.70.doc/diag/understanding/jni_refs.html)